# "Candidates answers your questions" for older elections links to recently held elections' meta page

Tags: bug, election

I checked with the election (site_address/election) page of Stack Overflow, Super User, and Workplace, and I noticed that on the page of any year's elections, *Candidates answers your questions* is always linked to the relevant page of the recently held elections.

So if you pick [the 2013 election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4) for Stack Overflow, the link to *[the] candidates answer your questions* links to the [relevant page of 2018 elections](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364498/2018-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire). The same goes for all the older elections pages of the three sites I tested with.

Comment: there is only one content page for /election. It gets updated when a new election takes place and with that the history is kind of gone.(unless if you look at its [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/revisions))

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel. I couldn't find that question in my search, probably because I didn't use correct keywords. Thanks, and I myself will flag it as a duplicate, as I don't intend to delete it. :-)

Comment: @rene Might I know how did you find that link to revisions?

Comment: They're stored in SEDE with PostTypeId = 7: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/924785/wiki-placeholders